# Datetime comparison within Pandas messing with datetime.time()

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, indexing, time

I have a large excel file with start and finish times for marathon runners. In order to determine the number of runners still on the course after delayed start times, I've tried to import the data into Pandas and use the built in pandas comparison in order to return a list of runners running at a certain time. At a given time x, runners on the course would have a start time <= x and a endtime > x. However in Pandas one of these is giving me an error.

I've imported the dataframe from Excel using the `read_exel` which automatically converts the start times and end times as `Datetime.time` objects. Here's some sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'name':['Bob','Sue','Joe'],
 'start_time':[datetime.time(6,50,0),datetime.t‌​ime(6,55,0),dateti‌​me.time(7,0,0)], 
 'start_time':[datetime.time(7,15,04),datetime.time(7,21,41)‌​,datetime.time(7,23,24)],})
```

Runners start at `6:50` and I would like to make a list of the amount of runners on the course every `4` minutes. So I've set up some variables to handle that:

```
race_start = datetime.datetime(100,1,1,6,50)
intervaul = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 4)
capture_time = race_start
```

Then I try to select the correct rows using Pandas built in selection

```
df[df.start_time <= capture_time.time() & df.end_time > capture_time.time()]
```

However I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot compare datetime.time and unicode

In fact, `df.start_time <= capture_time.time()` is perfectly fine and runs, but `df.end_time <= capture_time.time()` returns this error.

I have no idea what is going on here and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add `()` twice only, first can be omit, but by best practices are used too:

```
pd[(pd.start_time <= capture_time.time()) & (pd.end_time <= capture_time.time())]
```

Or maybe `dtype` of column `end_time` is not `datetime`, so you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
pd.end_time = pandas.to_datetime(pd.end_time)
```

I think name for `DataFrame` is better `df`, then you can use:

```
import pandas as pd

df.end_time = pd.to_datetime(df.end_time)
```

Comment: I'm going to edit my original post to make it more clear. In my haste I named my dataframe pd, when in reality I'm using df. 

However I don't think that's the issue. When I run `type(df.end_time[0])` I am returned datetime.time. Also I get the same original error when I run the code `df[df.end_time > capture_time.time()]` So I don't think it's a grouping problem.

Comment: Can you add some sample of data? 3 -4 rows?

Comment: Maybe you can use `df = pd.DataFrame({'end_time':[datetime.time(10,11,10),datetime.time(11,10,23),datetime.time(12,12,4)],
                   'start_time':[datetime.time(10,11,7),datetime.time(11,10,20),datetime.time(12,12)],})`

Comment: And change it as you need.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for helping me through this!

Comment: What was problem?

Comment: Sorry, that was misleading. I meant I fixed the original post with data. I'm still having the same problem...

Comment: Yes, I think problem is with data in column `end_time`. give me a time, I am working on it.

Comment: Oh my god. You were totally right. There was a single entry that was misentered so Pandas didn't convert the entire column to `datetime.time`. Thank you so much!!